# Open a link to another tab in Angular

Tags: angular

this is my URL path `this.router.navigate(['bd-activity/dynamicform', { id: event.customer_id, opportunity_id: event._id  }]);` I want it to open in another tab.

I have tried this (URL, _blank). that is not working here. I am working on angular 11. if you guys have any suggestions then please tell me.
I'm a beginner with Angular, I want to know how to create the Angular 5 File upload part, I'm trying to find any tutorial or doc, but I don't see anything anywhere. Any idea for this? And I tried ng4-files but it's not working for

Answer (score 1):

Just add `target="_blank"` to the

```
  <a mat-raised-button target="_blank" [routerLink]="['/bd-activity/dynamicform', 
      id: event.customer_id, opportunity_id: event._id]"
      class="theme-btn bg-grey white-text mx-2 mb-2">
      Open in New Window
  </a>
```

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

replying on top Priyanka answer, I'm assuming you are passing the link with query parameter

```
<a mat-raised-button target="_blank" [routerLink]="['/bd-activity/dynamicform']" 
[queryParams]="{id: event.customer_id, opportunity_id: event._id}"> 
Open in New Window 
</a>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ksszyb?file=src/app/app.component.html